# Doctrine Sqlite function IF

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

I faced problem, write unit test, using sqlite for it, for some query using doctrine extension for `IF ELSE` and when running test have error with that

[image]

for another error,md5 or concat I create sqlite function in PostConnectEventSubscriber class in postConnect function
[image]
in this part I use `ifelse`
[image]

this is my extension 
[image]
[image]
Now I create stub without logic, but how implementation this for sqlite ?

```
$args->getConnection()
        ->getWrappedConnection()
        ->sqliteCreateFunction('IF', function ($st) {
            return '';
        });
```

Comment: Please try to use English and not SMSish. Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: IF is not standard SQL. Use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case).

Comment: I don't want change query, only create sqlite function way interesting

Answer (score 1):

SQLLite does not support advanced conditional statements, you should use `CASE` instead of `IF...ELSE`.

Comment: I know that, that's why I create sqlite function, like md5 or concat and for IF what create too. I don't want change query, only create sqlite function way